# Calling Passport.js request.logout() from the client side when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, passport.js

Please help me understand/implement Passport.js logout functionality in this scenario :

On my server side , I have defined login, and logout (among some others) routes.

This is my routes.js implementation :

```
const 
  router = require('express').Router(),
  ensureAuth = require('../../authentication/auth-middleware'),
  config = require('../../configs/oidc-config');


module.exports = function routerCreate(passport){

  router.get('/login', 
    function(req, res, next) {
      passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', 
        { 
          response: res,                      // required
          resourceURL: config.resourceURL,    // optional. Provide a value if you want to specify the resource.
          customState: 'my_state',            // optional. Provide a value if you want to provide custom state value.
          failureRedirect: '/' 
        }
      )(req, res, next);
    },
    function(req, res, next){
      console.log('---AFTER LOGIN AUTH---');
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  );

  router.get('/authenticated',
    function(req, res, next){
      if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
        return res.sendStatus(200);
      }
      res.sendStatus(req.isAuthenticated() ? 200 : 401);
    }
  );

  router.post('/openid/return',
    function(req, res, next) {
      passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', 
        { 
          response: res,  // required
          failureRedirect: '/'  
        }
      )(req, res, next);
    },
    function(req, res) {
      console.log('We received a return from AzureAD.');
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  );

  router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.session.destroy(function(err) {
      console.log('FOUND LOG OUT');
      req.logOut();
      res.redirect(config.destroySessionUrl);
    });
  });

  return {
    baseRoute: '/api/auth',
    router: router
  };
}
```

And this is the client side implementation , this is where I am trying to figure out how to call req.logout method from above (server side).

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import {UserContext, HeaderContext} from '../../../context';
import mslogin from '../account-status/mslogin.png';


// const {router} = //require('../../../../../../api/routers/authentication/authentication-router');
export function MSLogin(){

    return(
        <div className='logout'>
            <div className='logout-container'>
                <div className='logout-box'>
                    <div className='logout-text'>{'Logout'}</div>
                    <a className='sign-out-link' href='/api/auth/logout' onClick={`Call req.logout`}>
                        <img src={mslogin} className="ms-img" alt="Microsoft" />
                        {'Sign in with Microsoft'} 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div className='spacer' />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

How do I call req.logout (on the server side) from the client side ?

Here is the structure of both my server side and client side application .

Server side structure : The routes are implemented in routers/authentication/authentication-router.js

[image: Server Side application structure]

Client side structure : The login screen is implemented in mslogin.js

[image: client side application structure]

Please help me out here. Thank you!

Comment: What's the issue? What happens when you click on the `anchor` tag? You need clarity in this question. An [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is highly suggested.

Comment: @DaneBrouwer after cliking on the anchor tag, the page reroutes to /auth/logout. 
Question :  How do I call req.logout method from the server side of the application to terminate the session?